# How can I enhance a legacy system without the legacy environment?

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere, legacy, websphere-6.1

I am updating a legacy application for my company and it runs on WebSphere v6.1. However, since the company has upgraded to WebSphere v8.5 as the company standard, they have gotten rid of WebSphere v6 instances for development.

Ideally this project should be upgraded from v6.1 to v8.5 before fix but that isn't in the current quarter's budget, and the enhancements are high priority. So now I have the enhancements coded, but I am stuck being unable to run and test the v6.1 application without proper application server instance.

Is there a way to enhance and run this application on the current version of WebSphere or another Web Application Server (Tomcat, Jetty, etc) and still have it compatible with WebSphere v6.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app on v8.5. WebSphere is backward compatible and will be able to run 6.1 apps. Just don't migrate project, when you import it to the RAD/Eclipse and make sure project facets are unchanged and point to J2EE 1.4 and Java 1.5.

Its much safer to test on higher WAS version than on other application server. And you can download v8.5 for development for free, if you dont have it.

Comment: Ok I use Eclipse Juno, I created new Enterprise Business Application and Dynamic Web Project the same versions as as the legacy code and moved the older code into these projects (because the WEbsphere v8.5 instance wasn't seeing the imported projects as these project types and I was unable to add them to the runnable instance); I then set Eclipse's compiler to 1.5 and added the Enterprise Business application to my WebSphere v8.5 instance and so far it looks like it works. Will this be able to be use on v6.1 if I were to export an EAR file from this, do you think?

Comment: Also the application's JRE library is currently the WebSphere v8.5's, should I make this my installed copy of JRE 1.5?

Comment: Make sure that you are creating Enterprise Application Project (EAR). I don't have Eclipse at hand, but in RAD I don't see project type like Enterprise business application. Make sure you are not creating Osgi bundle as it wont work on WAS v6.1. You should be able to run it, if Ear will be 1.4, web project 2.4 and java source and compile set to 1.5.